# What is a good way to share templates across apps with separate codebases?

Tags: ruby, git, backbone.js, heroku, amazon-s3

We have one Sinatra app and one Backbone app.

I saw [Sharing the same codebase across multiple apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227697/sharing-the-same-codebase-across-multiple-apps) but didn't understand it or how I could implement it.

This question is not really specific to Sinatra or Backbone; it could be pretty much any apps. Using Heroku and Git

One idea is to put the HTML on S3, but we aren't using S3 to store HTML. And how would you get it from Git onto S3? It seems very convoluted.

So, is there a good way of sharing HTML templates between the apps?

Comment: Can you put both apps inside the same repository? For example `sinatra/` and `backbone/` and have another directory called `common/`?

Comment: No, they are separate repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do it by having a containing parent directory, and well-defined paths to the common files, and by having a common YAML file used to tell different apps where to look.

Create a common YAML file that contains a Hash, with the keys being a common-name for a particular resource or path to resources, and the value being the absolute path to that on the disk.

For instance:

```
---
html: /absolute/path/to/shared/html
images:  /absolute/path/to/shared/images
main_css:  /absolute/path/to/shared/styles.css
```

Load that using Ruby with:

```
require 'yaml'

SHARED_RESOURCES = YAML.load_file('/absolute/path/to/shared_resources.yaml')
# => {"html"=>"/absolute/path/to/shared/html", "images"=>"/absolute/path/to/shared/images", "main_css"=>"/absolute/path/to/shared/styles.css"}
```

Use the resulting `SHARED_RESOURCES` hash to retrieve the information you need:

```
main_css = SHARED_RESOURCES['main_css'] 
# => "/absolute/path/to/shared/styles.css"
```

You can use that same YAML file from *ANY* language that can read YAML, or where you can open that file and parse its contents. At that point, all your code-bases can play from the same sheet of music, and will know how to access the common files when necessary.

For instance, from Perl:

```
use YAML;

$SHARED_RESOURCES = Load('
---
html: /absolute/path/to/shared/html
images:  /absolute/path/to/shared/images
main_css:  /absolute/path/to/shared/styles.css
');

print $SHARED_RESOURCES->{'main_css'}, "\n";
>> /absolute/path/to/shared/styles.css
```

If you want to get fancier, use a database to hold those shared resources. Either way, the idea is there's just one place for the code to look for a particular resource/file.